# Passing Arrays ByRef, Subscript Out of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass a number of arrays from my `Main` subroutine to another subroutine to get loaded. I use `ByRef` to pass them as pointers so I can continue using them in the `Main` sub after they have been loaded. I am also passing a dictionary to the load sub.

When I start to loop through the arrays within the `Build_Objects` sub, I encounter

> Subscript Out of Range

My simplified code:

```vb
Sub Main()
    
    '//Declarations
    Dim arr_data() As Variant
    Dim dict_headers As Object
    Dim arr_head1() As Variant, arr_head2() As Variant
    Dim arr_platform() As Variant
    
    
    '//Setting
    Set dict_headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    

    'before main, build objects required
    Call Build_Objects(arr_head1, arr_head2, dict_headers, arr_platform)

    .
    .
    .

End Sub
```

```vb
Sub Build_Objects(ByRef arr_head1P As Variant, ByRef arr_head2P As Variant, ByVal dict_headP As Object, ByRef arr_plat As Variant)
    
    '//Declarations
    Dim i_arr As Long
    ReDim arr_plat(1 To 9, 1 To 4)
    
    
    '//Arrays
    arr_head1P = Array("First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Phone", "Phone", "Phone", "Phone", "Zip", "Country", "DOB", "Gender")
    arr_head2P = Array("fn", "ln", "email", "Google_ph1", "FB_ph1", "Google_ph2", "FB_ph2", "POSTCODE", "COUNTRY_CODE", "CUSTOMER_DOB", "CUSTOMER_GENDER")
    
    '//Dictionary
    For i_arr = LBound(arr_head1P) To UBound(arr_head1P)
        dict_headP.Add arr_head2P(i_arr), arr_head1P(i_arr)
    Next i_arr
    
End Sub
```

The Subscript error occurs when `i_arr = 1` on the array `arr_head2P`. But as you can see below, before it enters the `For` loop the `arr_headP2` is loaded correctly and `arr_head2P(1)` should return `ln` not an error?

[image]

Comment: Why are you passing two arrays but then defning them in your sub?

Comment: Place a break point on `dict_headP.Add arr_head2P(i_arr), arr_head1P(i_arr)` and use F8 thereafter. Try to find out why the code processes `arr_i = 0` but not `arr_i  = 1`. I've also been wondering if the dictionary is empty. This kind of riddles often occur not because the code is faulty but because the testing procedure is.

Comment: @SJR He wants to use their values later in the main sub. He says so. First paragraph of question.

Comment: I'm able to replicate the issue. I think there is some sort of memory reference issue, on the second iteration of the loop. At least on my computer, the bounds for `arr_head2P` get changed, which is causing the error. I'd refactor this code so you can pass the arrays `ByVal` instead.

Comment: @Variatus - so why not populate them in the main sub?

Comment: I think I see the issue now, although I think this code should be refactored anyway. Replace `Dim arr_head1 As Variant(), arr_head2 As Variant()` with `Dim arr_head1 As Variant, arr_head2 As Variant`.

Comment: @Variatus that's what I did to get the screenshot. It process `0`, but fails on `1`.

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks for the heads up. Would there be any reason why the array bounds get changed? Super confused..

Comment: @SJR the point is to keep population separate to have a cleaner `Main`

Comment: @Dean Good question. I'm entirely not sure, maybe someone here can offer an explanation.

Comment: @RyanWildry that change in declaration fixed it. Any ideas why that works? Please add as an answer so I can mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some sort of memory reference issue going on here, replace `Dim arr_head1 As Variant(), arr_head2 As Variant()` with `Dim arr_head1 As Variant, arr_head2 As Variant`

Comment: Cheers, thanks. Hopefully some VBA god on here will be able to shed more light on the issue if they read this!